# Joint multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

If $\mathbf{y}$ has a multivariate normal distribution $N_n(\mathbf{a},\sigma^2\mathbf{I})$, can I say that $(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{a}^\intercal\mathbf{y})$ also has a multivariate normal distribution?

EDIT:

This is true. Any linear transformation of multivariate normal is normal. Consider $\mathbf{B} = (\mathbf{I}, \mathbf{a}^\intercal)$ where $\mathbf{I}$ is $n\times n$ identity. Then $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{y} = (\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{a}^\intercal\mathbf{y}) \sim \text{N}_{n+1}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{a}, \sigma^2\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^\intercal)$.

Comment: If $y$ is one-dimensional $N(a,\sigma^2)$, then $(y,ay)$ does not follow a bivariate normal distribution for $a\neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{a}$ has to be nonzero! good catch

Comment: That's not my point. I was trying to provide a counter-example. Take for instance $a=1$ in my example, then $(y,ay)=(y,y)$ has mass on the diagnonal and hence can not be normal. Doesn't that contraditct your statement?

Comment: @StefanHansen Every affine transform of every normal distribution is normal. For example, if y is one-dimensional normal, then (y,ay) is bivariate normal for every a, zero or nonzero. The only thing is that affine transforms of a normal distribution with density can be concentrated on a strict affine subspace, that is, be normal distributions without density.

Comment: "EDIT2: a must be nonzero" No.

Comment: @Did: Thank you for the clarification. I realize that I mistakenly thought that every normal distribution admits a density.